# UITableView is not reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am making an App that uses a `UITableView` and `UITableViewController`. However, when I call `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the `UITableViewController`, nothing happens, (`tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not called). What should I do?

```
- (void) UserChangedAmmountAndCurrency: (NSNotification*) notification {
    self.localBank.activeAmmount=((NSNumber*)[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"newAmmount"]).doubleValue;
    self.localBank.activeCurrency=[self.localBank.worldBank requestCurrencyForLocalBank:((NSString*)[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"newISO4217Currency"])];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSNumber *ammount= [self.localBank ammountForElementAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    VIPCurrency* currency=[self.localBank currencyForElementAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellWithCurrencyAndAmmount";
    VIPConversionCell* cell=[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.longCurencyIdentifier.text=currency.longName;
    cell.shortCurrencyIdentifier.text=currency.shortName;
    cell.textfieldForAmmount.text=ammount.stringValue;
    return cell;
}
```

EDIT:
I've done some extra testing. Ive tested that the tableview datasource and delegate are the viewcontroller that I use to call the reload method, which was ok. I've also noticed something  else weird. When calling reloadData, neither `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` nor `numberOfRowsInSection:` is called. I feel like I'm failing to do a basic thing before calling reloadData, but I don't know what. Could it be that I must somehow specifically set cells as out of date?

EDIT: I've also checked that the method was called in the Main Thread, which was also ok

Comment: Your code fails to handle the case when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil ...

Comment: I bet you did not set the implementer of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: as the data source of your table view.  Or you did not assign the tableView property.  Try logging self.tableView.  Is it nil?

Comment: Should I be setting delegates and data sources for my table view when I'm using storyBoards to create a tableview? Also, the data loads just fine the first time, but when I change my model and ask my tableview to reload, it does not call the data source cellFor ... - method. What could be the problem?

Comment: Verec, would there be a reason that I would want to return something else then nill from this method when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nill? I thought there would be a bug anyway if that was the case. Is there some different philosophy for handling the case of hill here?

Comment: I've checked explicitly using the Log function, and the view's datasource is set correctly and the view itself is very much alive... :(

Comment: what is your implementations of numberOfSection and rowsInSection if either is set to 0 you may see no data.

Comment: Also when you update the data are you sure the variables are created properly and also properly retained?

Comment: numbersOfSection always returns 1 and rowsInSection return the length of the array in the model that hold the currencies it displays. Ive checked with the debugger, and the data is nicely updated in the model.

Comment: I just don't understand why 'tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath' is not being called by the tableview. All the connections seem to be plugged in

Comment: I don't see anything in what you posted that would cause your problem. Do you know that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called (by logging)? Is the table populated the first time from UserChangedAmmountAndCurrency: or some other way?

Comment: Yep, I know it by logging. It's called when creating the table the first time, but not after. I don't know exactly which methods are responsible for creating the table the first time however, but it's not UserChangedAmmountAndCurrency:.

Comment: You say delegate and data source are connected, is `self.tableView`?

Comment: Yes, that is also connected. (self==self.tableView.delegate && self==self.tableview.dataSource) is YES

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that comment. I don't think the problem is in the code you posted.

Comment: @verec, if you already registered a `nib` with reusable identifier, in iOS5+ the `UITableView` automatically will create you a valid cell for you if there is not reusable cell in the queue; therefore the pointer never will be `nil`, and you don't need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of checking for `nil` from `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier` call is to create a new cell and return it. Unless you created a cell with the given identifier before and is in reusable pool, that method will return `nil`. So, as **@Verec** mentioned, you should check for `nil` and create the cell yourself and `return`.

Comment: I created the cell with the identifier as a prototype cell in the storyboard, so a new cell will be created and given when the queue is empty.

Comment: No, you don't need to check for nil anymore. According to Apple, you're supposed to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:, but I've noticed that it doesn't seem to matter. As long as you make your cell in the storyboard, and you have the correct identifier, it should work. Besides, the OP said the table was loaded fine the first time.

Comment: if you already registered a `nib` with reusable identifier, in iOS5+ the `UITableView` automatically will create you a valid cell for you if there is not reusable cell in the queue; therefore the pointer never will be `nil`, and you don't need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Set table view delegate in `.xib` file and `.h` file `(UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate)`

`[myTableView reloadData];`

Answer (score -2):

You just need to add

```
UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
```

in .h

example

```
@interface yourviewcontroller : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Merely declaring conformance to the protocols will affect nothing; it only means that the controller *can* be a table view data source/delegate. The questioner must also set this controller as the data source and delegate of the table view in question.